# Why isnt this regexp backtrack working

Tags: java, regex

I have tried to use the following kind of regex

```
([_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4}))|(FakeEmail:)|(Email:)|(\1\2)|(\1\3)
```

(pretend the \1 is the email regex group, and \2 is FakeEmail: and \3 is Email: because I didnt count the parens to figure out the real grouping)

What I am trying to do is say "Find the word email: and if you find it, pick up any email address following the word."

That email regex I got off some other question on stack overflow.

my test string could be something like

```
    "This guy is spamming me from
FakeEmail: fakeemailAdress@someplace.com
 but here is is real info:
Email: testemail@someplace.com"
```

Any tips? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm either quite confused as to what you're trying to do, or your Regex is just very wrong.  In particular:

Why do you have `Email:` at the end, instead of the beginning - to match your example?

Why do you have both your `Email:` and your `\1\2` separated by pipe characters, almost as if they're in fields?  This is compiling the pattern as ORs.  (Find the email pattern, OR the word "Email:", OR whatever `\1\2` will end up meaning as it is out of context here.)

If all you're trying to do is match something like `Email: testemail@someplace.com`, you don't need any backtracking.

Something like this is probably all you need:

```
Email:\s+([_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4}))
```

Also, I'd strongly advise against trying to validate an email address so strictly.  You may want to read http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx .  I'd simplify the pattern to something more along the lines of:

```
Email:\s+(\S+)*@(\S+\.\S+)
```

Comment: I modified the example to be more realistic. I had the regex structurued like that because I really want to try to pick out the fake and the real emails, re-using the email regex

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
(Fake)?Email: *([_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4}))
```

And captured group `\1` will be empty if it's a real email and contain "Fake" if it's a fake email, while `\2` will be the email itself.

Do you actually want to capture it if it's `FakeEmail` though? If you want to capture all `Email` but ignore all `FakeEmail` then do:

```
\bEmail: *([_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4}))
```

The word boundary prevents the `Email` bit from matching "FakeEmail".

**UPDATE**: note your regex only matches lowercase since it's got `a-z` in the `[]` everywhere but not `[A-Z]`. Make sure you feed your regex into the java match function with the ignore case switch. i.e.:

```
Pattern.compile("(Fake)?Email: .....", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
```

Comment: I modified the example to be more realistic. I had the regex structurued like that because I really want to try to pick out the fake and the real emails, re-using the email regex

Comment: I am eventually going to want to capture all the emails - i just only care about the real one right now. Also, this doesnt quite seem to work

Comment: This seems like it will only pick up "Email" and not "FakeEmail" OR "Email" followed by an email address

Comment: The first regex captures both `Email` and `FakeEmail` by virtue of the `(Fake)?Email`.

Comment: Also, it probably doesn't work on your test string because you have to enable the case-insensitive switch (note how the regex only does lower-case but your test string has an upper-case email address).

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to match all type of email address:

```
String text = "This guy is spamming me from\n" +
    "FakeEmail: fakeemail+Adress@someplace.com\n" +
    "fakeEmail: \n" +
    "fakeemail@someplace.com" +
    "but here is is real info:\n" +
    "Email: test.email+info@someplace.com\n";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?i)(?s)Email:\\s*([_a-z\\d\\+-]+(\\.[_a-z\\d\\+-]+)*@[a-z\\d-]+(\\.[a-z\\d-]+)*(\\.[a-z]{2,4}))").matcher(text);
while(m.find())
    System.out.printf("Email is [%s]%n", m.group(1));
```

This will match email text:

- appearing on different lines by using `(?s)`
- ignoring case comparison by using `(?i)`
- Email address with a period `.` in it
- Email address with a plus sign `+` in it

**OUTPUT: From above code is**

```
Email is [fakeemail+Adress@someplace.com]
Email is [fakeemail@someplace.comb]
Email is [test.email+info@someplace.com]
```